# date filtering is not working in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-grid

```
 function BindGrid(dData) {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource:
                    {
                        data: dData,
                        schema: {
                            data: "Data",
                            total: "Total"
                        },
                        serverPaging: false,
                        serverFiltering: false,
                        serverSorting: false
                    },
            filterable: {
                ui: function (element) {
                    element.kendoDatePicker({
                        format: "MMM dd, yyyy",
                        parseFormats: ["dd-MMMM-yyyy"]
                    });
                }
            },
            sortable: true,
            pageable: {
                pageSize: 100,
                pageSizes: [100, 200, 300, 400],
                //messages: {
                //    itemsPerPage: "Products",
                //    display: "{0}-{1} from {2} Products",
                //    empty: "No data",
                //    allPages: "Show All"
                //}
            },

            sortable: {
                allowUnsort: false
            },
            columns: [
                { field: "Person", title: "@Html.LanguageLabel("Product.Person")", width: "180px" },
                { field: "DownloadedDate", title: "@Html.LanguageLabel("Product.DownloadedDate")", type: "date", width: "100px", template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(DownloadedDate), 'MMM dd, yyyy') #" },
                { field: "DownloadedTime", title: "@Html.LanguageLabel("Product.DownloadedTime")", width: "100px" },
    { field: "Company", title: "@Html.LanguageLabel("Product.Company")", width: "180px" },
    { field: "StateName", title: "@Html.LanguageLabel("State")", width: "150px" },
    { field: "PhoneNumber", title: "@Html.LanguageLabel("Product.PhoneNumber")", width: "120px" },
    { field: "EmailId", title: "@Html.LanguageLabel("Product.Email")", width: "250px" },

            ],
        });
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve] and ask a question. Use formatting to facilitate reading.
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Please add more context on your issue. "Date filtering is not working" can mean so many things; Date filter isn't appearing, date filter filtering the incorrect date, date filter not filtering at all etc. Also, format your code as @Yunnosch suggested.

Answer (score 2):

There is a known issue with Kendo Grid in which the date filtering does not ignore the timestamp (i.e. hours/minutes/seconds) and does not match the month/day/year only.